# Por qué el ciclo for se comporta diferente cuando declaro una variable dentro que fuera?

Tags: javascript

Quiero usar for loop para iterar de 0 a 5 e imprimir la suma de todos los números.

```js
let sum = 0; 
 for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
   sum += i
   console.log(sum)
  } // 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15
```

```js
for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
     let sum = 0 
     sum += i
     console.log(sum)
     } // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 5):

Es porque cuando la variable está dentro del for, lo que sucede es que por cada ciclo se inicializa sum en 0, luego se le suma el valor de i y finalmente se imprime ese valor.

En el caso de la variable afuera lo que sucede es que nunca se vuelve a inicializar sum en 0 en cada ciclo, por lo que en ese caso al valor de sum acumulado le suma i y luego muestra el valor.